# How to change style of nested element on uwp

Tags: c#, uwp

I have an app load articles from internet and I want to change the `BlockQuote` on it so I create a custom style but the `BlockQuote` style never change !

to change it I have to delete `<P>` and `</p>` from the html code ! so i need to use a nested style but `DocumentStyle` couldn't set it any ideas...

Here's my code:

```
    <!-- my style for html -->
<Style TargetType="controls:HtmlBlock" x:Key="HtmlPersonalStyle">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ApplicationHeaderForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="DocumentStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <controls:DocumentStyle>
                <controls:DocumentStyle.P>
                    <controls:ParagraphStyle Margin="0,24,0,24" />
                </controls:DocumentStyle.P>
                <controls:DocumentStyle.BlockQuote>
                    <controls:ParagraphStyle Foreground="{StaticResource NavigationPaneButton}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                </controls:DocumentStyle.BlockQuote>
                <controls:DocumentStyle.Ul>
                    <controls:ContainerStyle Margin="0,24,0,24" />
                </controls:DocumentStyle.Ul>
                <controls:DocumentStyle.H1>
                    <controls:ParagraphStyle FontSizeRatio="2" />
                </controls:DocumentStyle.H1>
                <controls:DocumentStyle.H2>
                    <controls:ParagraphStyle />
                </controls:DocumentStyle.H2>
                <controls:DocumentStyle.Li>
                    <controls:ListStyle Bullet="*"/>
                </controls:DocumentStyle.Li>
                <controls:DocumentStyle.Span>
                    <controls:TextStyle Foreground="#FF104F83" FontStyle="Normal"/>
                </controls:DocumentStyle.Span>
                <controls:DocumentStyle.A>
                    <controls:TextStyle Foreground="{StaticResource NavigationPaneButton}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                </controls:DocumentStyle.A>
                <controls:DocumentStyle.Cite>
                    <controls:TextStyle Foreground="{StaticResource NavigationPaneButton}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                </controls:DocumentStyle.Cite>
                <controls:DocumentStyle.YouTube>
                    <controls:ImageStyle HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </controls:DocumentStyle.YouTube>
                <controls:DocumentStyle.Figure>
                    <controls:ContainerStyle Margin="0,24,0,24"/>
                </controls:DocumentStyle.Figure>
                <controls:DocumentStyle.Time>
                    <controls:TextStyle FontSizeRatio="0.9" FontStyle="Italic" />
                </controls:DocumentStyle.Time>
            </controls:DocumentStyle>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Hope anyone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's looks like you're using `AppStudio` plugin in your app so to edit the nested element you have to install the `AppStudio` code from [here](https://github.com/wasteam/waslibs) and after that you can edit the element before it's write and without using any styles!

Answer (score 1):

> I have an app load articles from internet and I want to change the BlockQuote on it so I create a custom style but the BlockQuote style never change

It seems like you are developing with Windows App Studio. By testing on my side, the `<blockquote>` style can be changed successfully by setting the `DocumentStyle.BlockQuote`. Even the `<blockquote>` nested inside the `<p>` tag, the style still can work well.

Here is my test HTML:

```
<header class="post-header">
    <time class="date">March 8, 2016 10:00 am</time>
    <h1 class="post-title">Building Hosted Web Apps with Windows App Studio</h1>
    <div><p><blockquote>test block quote </blockquote></p></div>
    <blockquote>test block quote 2</blockquote> 
</header>
```

And the updated style:

```
<Style x:Key="sampleStyle" TargetType="was:HtmlBlock">
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#666" />
   <Setter Property="DocumentStyle">
       <Setter.Value>
           <was:DocumentStyle>
               <was:DocumentStyle.P>
                   <was:ParagraphStyle Margin="0,24,0,24" />
               </was:DocumentStyle.P>
               <was:DocumentStyle.BlockQuote>
                   <was:ParagraphStyle Foreground="Red" FontWeight="Bold"/>
               </was:DocumentStyle.BlockQuote>
               ...
           </was:DocumentStyle>
       </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
```

And the testing result:
[image]

I updated the style based on the [HTMLBlock official sample](https://github.com/wasteam/waslibs/tree/master/samples/AppStudio.Uwp.Samples/Pages/HtmlBlock) which you can reference. So please ensure that the custom style is exactly setting to the `HTMLBlock` on your side. If you still have issues, try to provide a minimal reproduced demo based on the official sample.

Additionally, currently [WindowsTemplateStudio](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsTemplateStudio) is recommended to use instead of Windows App Studio. Details please reference [this article](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/06/30/windows-app-studio-sunset/#oFEqQOJalcD2M28S.97).

Comment: Thanks for your help but on my code the `<p>` inside the `<blockquote>` so there's nothing changed any ideas ...

Comment: @louay, if the latest tag is `<p>`, you need to update the `P` style.     `<was:DocumentStyle.P>
         <was:ParagraphStyle Margin="0,24,0,24"  Foreground="Red" FontWeight="Bold"/>
     </was:DocumentStyle.P>`

Comment: If i Change `<p>` the font color for all my html will change with my `blockquote` any ideas @Sunteen

Comment: @louay, that comes the issue, why you need `<p>` inside? Your requirements come to have special for only this one which I think it is not recommended. And As I mentioned in the reply, Windows App Studio is sunset,could I know why you persist to use it?

Comment: Im not using an app studio app but i have a wordpress and the `blockquote` have `<p>` inside and i don't know what to do

Comment: @louay, just deleted the `<p>`.

Comment: There's no way to delete it ! I think that i should delete it by edit my save file using find and replace!